# How to deal with little holes in shower's tiled wall

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, hole-repair

My shower wall had a tiny towel rack which was installed with screws.  Because of the location, I tended to bang my head on the corner when coming in close to the faucets to adjust the temperature.  I took it out.  I couldn't leave holes, so I sealed the holes with screws and washers.  That is effective in that it keeps the water out of the holes, but I don't like the way it looks.  What would be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatives:

1. Remove screws and fully dry the holes and tiles there. Then back fill the holes with a colored epoxy that color matches close to the tile.
2. Back fill the holes with a tile grout material of color similar to the tile color.
3. Break or cut out the tile with the holes and replace with one of the spare left over tiles from the original installation job. (Hoping that you have such tile).

Comment: Is that *tile* grout?  Would I just buy the regular grout at the hardware store?  Should I build it up in two or three layers, letting dry in between?

Comment: Yes it is tile grout. I corrected the spelling m--->l. Grout, when mixed properly for use, will be firm enough that can be used to fill the holes all in one go. That would include leveling the patch with an appropriate tool such as a putty knife. Make sure to clean the hole well to eliminate any soap scum or loose debris.